# Should need webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ to show jsp page in spring boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I know, it's very silly question. I want to know clearly, why jsp pages serve from webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ folder? where thymeleaf pages serve from src/main/resource folder in spring boot?
I knew that, WEB-INF is safe folder for serve any page, then thymeleaf pages why not (most of tutorial use)?
can you explain explicitly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jsp pages can also be served from src/main/resources. Here is an example - https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-mvc-app-with-jsp

Comment: normally thymeleaf serve from resources/templates/ but when I was try to serve jsp from that folder I get not found error. Now it's serve from web-inf/jsp folder.